# How would you go about debugging Specified Cast is not valid, using dates?

Tags: c#, sql

https://ibb.co/DkKdpnL

This is the code im using in the Database controller. Im sure there is nothing wrong with this code but i keep on getting the error message when I select a date from the Monthly calender Picker.

````
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            SqlCommand command;
            Collection<StockItem> items;
            try
            {
                DateTime input;
                DateTime.TryParse(date, out input);
                command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StockItem WHERE DATEDIFF(day, stockItemExpiryDate,'" + input.ToString() + "') >= 0 ORDER BY stockItemShelfNumber", cnMain);
                cnMain.Open();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                items = new Collection<StockItem>();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        StockItem item = new StockItem();
                        item.expiryDate = reader.GetDateTime(1).ToShortDateString();
                        item.shelfNumber = reader.GetString(2);
                        item.numberInStock = reader.GetInt32(3) + "";
                        item.productRef = reader.GetInt32(4) + "";
                        SqlConnection connection = newConn();
                        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT productPackaging FROM Product WHERE productID =" + item.productRef + ";", connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                        String description = "";
                        if (reader2.HasRows)
                        {
                            reader2.Read();
                            description = reader2.GetString(0);
                        }
                        reader2.Close();
                        connection.Close();
                        item.productRef = description;
                        items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                cnMain.Close();
                this.items = items;
                return items;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                cnMain.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            return null;
        }```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Im sure there is nothing wrong with this code" That's almost *always* a good signal that there will be things wrong with the code, in my experience. (As a concrete first problem, you're ignoring the result of `DateTime.TryParse`. Are you definitely happy with silently using `DateTime.MinValue` if `date` isn't a valid date/time value?) Next, you're converting `input` to a string rather than using a parameterized query, which has all kinds of potential culture-oriented issues. You haven't told us where the exception is thrown, which makes it hard to help you further.

Comment: Oh, and using `SELECT *` but then assuming a specific order of columns doesn't seem like a great idea. Even if it *does* work, it's very brittle.

Comment: More generally, the less sure you are of your code's correctness, the more likely you are to find the problems - because when you're *sure* it's correct, it's really easy to just skim over the code *assuming* it really is. When you think the problem *is* in your code, you're more likely to look carefully at every single line.

Comment: (You might want to use a debugger to call `reader.GetName(i)` for whatever value of `i` is being used on line 699... and check whether it's the column you expect.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Relooked at my sql tables now and the order of the StockItemExpiryDate wasnt matching the order that i set in the code(line 699). So that error message is gone, but now the only issue is that it doesnt show the items thats expired, so thats the next thing to debug

Comment: @Furqaan plus you do know that the ordinal is 0 based yea?  i.e. reader.GetDateTime(1) is going to be the 2nd column in your result set. If the dateTime is the first you would want reader.GetDateTime(0)

Comment: And it's your lucky day to get welcomed to stack overflow by @JonSkeet... it's quite literally the royal carpet treatment

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I assume the exception is being raised by

```
item.expiryDate = reader.GetDateTime(1).ToShortDateString();
```

Logically, field 1 (The second column) in your StockItem table isn't a Date/Time. I'd check your table, and if you're sure that's right, maybe use `reader.GetValue(1)` instead, and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you, that is right. I had to swap the headings in the tables to match the code in the controller

Comment: This pretty much highlights Jon's comment about using SELECT * being brittle- changing the headings broke your code.

Comment: do you suggest re typing the select * part? what do you suggest i do

Comment: Well, I don't know your table, but basically, using 'SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, etc. FROM' will mean regardless of how your table's arranged, the code will read them in that order.